# write multiples lines example code in @doc auto-format error

Tags: elixir, markdown, documentation

The function doc is as follows:

```elixir
  @doc """


  input：


  output:
   

  ## example

    max_height = 5
    max_length = 5
    is_used = true
    result =
      InventoryMap.constrcut_initial_map(
        max_length,
        max_height,
        is_used,
        max_length,
        max_height,
        is_used
      )

  """
```

The actual result is as follows:

[image]

How to make

```elixir
max_height = 5
max_length = 5
is_used = true
```

as part of the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExDoc uses Markdown. Code blocks are represented by 4 characters of indentation. You need to indent by 2 more characters.

```elixir
  @doc """
  input：

  output:

  ## example
      max_height = 5
      max_length = 5
      is_used = true
      result =
        InventoryMap.constrcut_initial_map(
          max_length,
          max_height,
          is_used,
          max_length,
          max_height,
          is_used
        )
  """
```

Or use backticks:

````elixir
  ## example
  ```
  max_height = 5
  max_length = 5
  etc...
  ```
````

---

[image]